# How to make a 3 column fully responsive image grid in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

What would be the best way to go about making a 3 column fully responsive image grid with a 10px margin on the left/right of the center image (responsive from 1280px all the way down to 320px) in HTML/CSS that has extensive cross-browser support?

Could I use a CSS propert such as: column-count? Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you generating images dynamically or entering manually?

Comment: The best way to go about doing this would be to try doing it. Then, if you can't get it working the way you want it to, come back here and share your code and the SA community will try and help you out. I wouldn't recommend column-count as it's not fully supported across all browsers.

Comment: 3 columns at 320px is going to be the squishiest thing ever. Consider using media queries to change your design when it starts to look awful.

Comment: I'm generating images dynamically with WordPress

Answer (score 8):

Your format itself is quite simple...

Let's assume this basic format at desktop size...

```
|*****|*|*****|*|*****|
|     | |     | |     |
|     | |     | |     |
|*****|*|*****|*|*****|
```

So, let's use 3.8% margins.

We need to calculate the width of our columns based on those margins.  We have two margins at 3.8% = 7.6%.

100% - 7.6% = 92.4% / 3 columns = 30.8%

So...

**CSS:**

```
.container { width: 100%; max-width: 1280px; min-width: 320px; margin: 0 auto; clear: both; }

.col-3 { float: left;  width: 30.8%; margin-right: 3.8%; }

.last { margin-right: 0; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3 last">
    </div>
</div>
```

You will want to use media queries to adjust this to a single column layout for mobile.

Comment: Could you add the code for media queries? tablet and mobile would be greatful.

Comment: Wonderful, solved my issue and I didn't use media queries. I just needed to adjust margin-right and I didn't use .last class

Comment: May I asked how you "adjust[ed] margin-right" and where?