# Picture location in HTML, anyone knows?

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML. I have this code which makes 9 picutres with HTML:

```
<a href=""><img src="fotos/photo.jpg" style="width: 160px; height: 160px;"></a>
```

I was wondering how I can make these pictures like this:

https://gyazo.com/cde734a459da86698fcb60363cdea272

Would it be better to use a framework with this or in HTML?

Comment: Using CSS you can do this... but also take a look at https://getbootstrap.com

Comment: You'll have to describe what you want better, but [here's one idea](https://css-tricks.com/seamless-responsive-photo-grid/). and there are probably others closer to your requirements on that site.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a 3 column fully responsive image grid in HTML/CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15550974/how-to-make-a-3-column-fully-responsive-image-grid-in-html-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with flex-box. See example:

```
<html>
<style>
.container{
display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
width:100vw;

}

.image{
display:flex;
width:33.3vw;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="image"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0I7wcbT.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0I7wcbT.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0I7wcbT.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0I7wcbT.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0I7wcbT.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0I7wcbT.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0I7wcbT.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0I7wcbT.jpg"></div>
    <div class="image"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/0I7wcbT.jpg"></div>
</div>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use display flex.

CSS

```
.container {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <a href=""><img src="fotos/photo.jpg" style="width: 160px; height: 160px;"></a>
  <!-- 9 times -->
</div>
```

Heres a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rardepwr/)